# How can I dynamically add a new level to JSON data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have two JSON objects and I want to combine them into one JSON object. Also, I want them to be added as sublevels in the output JSON object.

**JSON Object 1**:

```
{ 
  Title: '7500',
  Year: '2019',
  Rated: 'R',
  Released: '18 Jun 2020',
  Runtime: '93 min',
  Genre: 'Action, Drama, Thriller'
}
```

**JSON Object 2**:

```
{
  Title: 'Deadpool',
  Year: '2016',
  Rated: 'R',
  Released: '12 Feb 2016',
  Runtime: '108 min',
  Genre: 'Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi'
}
```

**Desired Output**:

```
responses: {
  7500: {
    Title: '7500',
    Year: '2019',
    Rated: 'R',
    Released: '18 Jun 2020',
    Runtime: '93 min',
    Genre: 'Action, Drama, Thriller'
  },
  Deadpool: {
    Title: 'Deadpool',
    Year: '2016',
    Rated: 'R',
    Released: '12 Feb 2016',
    Runtime: '108 min',
    Genre: 'Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi'
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dynamic property name ([computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015))

```js
const obj1 = {
  Title: "7500",
  Year: "2019",
  Rated: "R",
  Released: "18 Jun 2020",
  Runtime: "93 min",
  Genre: "Action, Drama, Thriller",
};

const obj2 = {
  Title: "Deadpool",
  Year: "2016",
  Rated: "R",
  Released: "12 Feb 2016",
  Runtime: "108 min",
  Genre: "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi",
};

const obj = {
  [obj1.Title]: obj1,
  [obj2.Title]: obj2,
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your two objects into an array, and then use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each object to an array of the form `[object.Title, object]`. Using this new array, you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert it to an object. By putting your objects into an array, you can extend this for multiple movie objects:

```js
const movies = [{ Title: '7500', Year: '2019', Rated: 'R', Released: '18 Jun 2020', Runtime: '93 min', Genre: 'Action, Drama, Thriller' }, { Title: 'Deadpool', Year: '2016', Rated: 'R', Released: '12 Feb 2016', Runtime: '108 min', Genre: 'Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi' }];

const result = Object.fromEntries(movies.map(obj => [obj.Title, obj]));
console.log(result);
```

As a side note, there is [no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Well, [that's](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) surprising.